# transpose a table in python

Tags: python, function, pivot, transpose

I have a table like this:[image]

I want to transpose it to this:[image]

I want to use python, but cannot figure out how to do it.  Can anyone help with this?
Thanks,
Ebi

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')  # or pd.read_csv('data.csv')
out = (df.pivot(index=['course_id', 'course_start'], columns='Labtes(unit)', values='Value')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   course_id course_start  A  B  C
0          0       5/4/17  1  2  3
1          1      5/25/17  4  5  6

>>> df
   course_id course_start Labtes(unit)  Value
0          0       5/4/17            A      1
1          0       5/4/17            B      2
2          0       5/4/17            C      3
3          1      5/25/17            A      4
4          1      5/25/17            B      5
5          1      5/25/17            C      6
```

**Note**: you can also do the same with pivot from [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) or [LibreOffice](https://books.libreoffice.org/en/CG71/CG7108-PivotTables.html)